# How do i make my Navbar overlap the rest of the page?

Tags: reactjs

I want my navbar to be fixed and stay above the rest of the page as i scroll down, but whenever i add the 'position: fixed;' function on the css page it disappears.

Here is the code for the navbar in JS and Css...

```
import Logo from '../../Images/mmt-white.png';
import './Navbar.css';

const Navbar = props => (

    <header className="Navbar">
        <nav className="Navbar__navigation">
            <div></div>
            <div className='Navbar__logo'><img src={Logo}/></div>
            <div className='spacer '/>
            <div className="Navbar_navigation-items">
                <ul>
                    <li><a  href="/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="/">Servicos</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="/">Depoimentos</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="/">Começando</a></li>
                    <li><a  href="/">Contacte-nos</a></li>    
                </ul>

            </div>
            <div className="Navbar_navigation_items_acessar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/">Acessar</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            
        </nav>
       
    </header>

);

export default Navbar;
```

And here is my app.js where i import all the pages and the navbar on top off them...

```
import Navbar from './components/NavBar/Navbar';
import Home from "./components/pages/HomePage/Home";
import Comecando from "./components/pages/Comecando/Comecando";
import Depoimentos from "./components/pages/Depoimentos/Depoimentos";
import Sac from "./components/pages/SAC/Sac";
import Servicos from "./components/pages/Servicos/Servicos";
import './App.css';


function App () {
    return(



      <div className='App'>
        <div>
         <Navbar/>
         </div>
         <Home/>
        <Servicos/>
        <Comecando/>
        <Depoimentos/>
        <Sac/>
      </div>
    );
  }

export default App;
```

and here is the css

```
.NavbarItems {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,rgb(49,56,64)0%,rgba(49, 56, 64, 1) 100%);
  height: 10vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1,2rem;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1; 
  position: relative;

}
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar-logo{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(15%, 10%);

}

.fa-react{
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1,6rem;

}


.nav-menu {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, auto);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  transform: translate(8%, 0%);
  list-style: none;
  margin-left: 10vh;
  text-align: center;
  width: 80vw;
  justify-content: end;
  padding-left: 10vh;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.nav-links {
  color:#edf0f1;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  padding-right: 2rem;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-transform: uppercase;

}

.nav-links:hover{
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: all 0.2s ease0;
  color: #0088a9;
  
  
}

.fa-bars{
  color: #ffffff;

}


button{
  margin-left: 10vh;
  right: 0;
  padding: 9px 25px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #edf0f1;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu-icon{
  display: none;
}

.nav-links-mobile{
  color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: Please post your CSS as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to add the following to your `NavBar` class in your `NavBar.css` file to add the positional properties like so:

```
left: 0;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index: 1; // increase this value if you have other elements at varying levels of elevation
```

Or you may want to add the following to your `NavBar` class in your `NavBar.css` file instead of `position: fixed` (it depends on the behavior you're looking for):

```
position: sticky;
top: 0; // vertical position you'd like the element to stick to
z-index: 1; // increase this value if you have other elements at varying levels of elevation
```

Comment: i try both way´s but it still doesn´t work ;( i will upload my css

Comment: The `className` you're using is `NavBar`, but I don't see that class is your CSS file. Did you mean `sticky`?

Comment: Dont worry its was my mistake, i had to position in my css... that why it was not working!